# Azure database for mysql - cross region read replica

Tags: disaster-recovery, azure-mysql-database

I'm using Azure database for mysql - Flexible server and we would like to have Disaster recovery in another Azure region. As per the below documentation, the cross region read replica is not supported. My question is what is the correct way to have cross region Disaster recovery?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/flexible-server/concepts-read-replicas

-Suresh

Comment: Can i please request for an answer..Appreciate any response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross region read replicas for MySQL Flexible Server is part of our backlog and will be coming soon. Meanwhile, you can leverage data-in replication to achieve the same.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-for-mysql-blog/cross-region-replication-using-data-in-replication-with-azure/ba-p/3563231

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

not all regions for the azure MySQL server supporting the replicating so the best way and the fastest one is to create another MYSQL server that is supporting the replicating
in the following ling you gonna find how to make the replication :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/db/replica?view=azure-cli-latest
try to create the server in westus for example i remember that is supporting the replication in another region